# Microsoft Graph API - is there a way to get the current user's groups filtered by their displayName?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, httprequest

I was trying to do something like this with the API to find specifc groups from the current user, but the API doesn't seem to support this type of request.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf?$filter=displayName eq 'Marketing Team'`

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "The specified filter to the reference property query is currently not supported.",
    }
}
```

I also tried this approach, and while it does work, it brings all the groups, regardless if the user is part of them or not.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=displayName eq 'Marketing Team' or displayName eq 'HR Team' or displayName eq 'IT Team'
```

I'm using the group results to assign authorities, so if I filter all the groups I will always get the three groups I'm looking for and everyone will have the three roles.
If I just bring all the groups from the current user and filter them after, it makes the login too slow for users that are part of +500 groups.

Is there a way to look for the current user's groups with filters, without filtering on the client side to be more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query will work, but you need to add `$count=true` to the URL and add `ConsistencyLevel` request header with value `Eventual`.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf?$filter=displayName eq 'Marketing Team'&$count=true

ConsistencyLevel=eventual
```

It's so called [advanced query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http) in Graph API